# Roblox Studio: if then else error, attempted everything

Tags: lua, game-engine, roblox

I don't know what is wrong, it keeps repeating the same error of:
[Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yBmEG.png)

```
local clicker = script.Parent.ClickDetector
local canclick = true

local chance = math.random(1,3)
if chance == 1 then 
clicker.MouseClick:connect(function(Player)
    if canclick then
        if Player:FindFirstChild("Stand").Value == "The World" then
            Player:FindFirstChild("Stand").Value = "Nightmare World"
            canclick = true
            Player:LoadCharacter()
            script.Parent:Remove()  
        else
    clicker.MouseClick:connect(function(Player)
    if canclick then
            Player:FindFirstChild("Stand").Value = "None"
            canclick = true
            Player:LoadCharacter()
            script.Parent:Remove()          
        end
    end
end)
```

I've tried putting ends and then replacing ends and even added parentheses, but nothing will work.
If you could somehow rewrite the code, or help me with it, that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The error message is correct, `clicker.MouseClick:connect(function(Player)` is missing a last )

Comment: @B.Go I know that, but how would I add that?

Comment: Regardless of the syntax error, I must point out that you are registering another click event within the first click event listener. This means that every time you click and `canclick` is `true`, you will create _another_ click event to set the Stand value to "None".

Answer (score 1):

```lua
local clicker = script.Parent.ClickDetector
local canclick = true

local chance = math.random(1,3)
if chance == 1 then 
clicker.MouseClick:connect(function(Player)
    if canclick then
        if Player:FindFirstChild("Stand").Value == "The World" then
            Player:FindFirstChild("Stand").Value = "Nightmare World"
            canclick = true
            Player:LoadCharacter()
            script.Parent:Remove()  
        else
            clicker.MouseClick:connect(function(Player)
                if canclick then
                    Player:FindFirstChild("Stand").Value = "None"
                    canclick = true
                    Player:LoadCharacter()
                    script.Parent:Remove()    
                end
            end) -- here
        end
    end
end)
```

You forgot the closing bracket and an end statement!  I highlighted it with a comment. :)  I didn't test it, but if it doesn't work I'll look over it again.

Comment: Ah- it's still broken, hopefully you can fix it. If you can thank you. It gives this new error now.
```Expected 'end' (to close 'then' at line 5), got <eof>

Comment: You forgot another end.
@Coalizeee at the end of the code, add another `end` on a new line.

Comment: Oh no, this is registering another click event _within_ the click event. That's going to cause all sorts of problems.

Comment: @StephenLeitnick Yes Crazyman ;)  I know but it's their code, not mine.